# use python pandas to write directly to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following script which queries ElasticSearch and writes the documents to CSV

```
documents = []
scanResp= helpers.scan(client=es, query=query, scroll= "10m", index="index-*-a",size=1000, clear_scroll=False, request_timeout=300)

for doc in scanResp:
    print('--- next document ----')
    row = doc['_source']
    print(row)
    document = {
        'artistAppearsAs': row['artistAppearsAs'],
        'isrc': row['isrc'],
        'artistId': row['artistAppearsAs'],
        'title': row['artistId']
    }
    documents.append(document)

df = pd.DataFrame(documents)
df.to_csv('../data/documents.csv', header=True, index=False, index_label=False)
```

i have about 400,000 documents, what is the correct way to write each document to the CSV file using Pd?

Comment: Is there some reason this approach isn't working for you?

Comment: no, it is working, i just feel that i have to create a list `documents` and from this create the csv file.

Comment: What you have shown here looks like it's a pretty good solution. If the concern is about how much data you are holding in memory, you could dump out a new CSV every thousand documents or so and then combine them at the end. You could also start by creating a `DataFrame` at the beginning and [appending](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to that rather than appending to a `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to store the documents in a list first, you can use [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

```py
scanResp = helpers.scan(client=es, query=query, scroll= "10m", index="index-*-a",size=1000, clear_scroll=False, request_timeout=300)

documents = pandas.DataFrame()

for doc in scanResp:
    print('--- next document ----')
    row = doc['_source']
    print(row)
    document = {
        'artistAppearsAs': row['artistAppearsAs'],
        'isrc': row['isrc'],
        'artistId': row['artistAppearsAs'],
        'title': row['artistId']
    }
    documents.append(document, ignore_index=True)


documents.to_csv('../data/documents.csv', header=True, index=False, index_label=False)
```